Getting a drain snake into a tight bend
Background
I have a drain in my basement laundry room that backs up every year. For the past 3 years, I've paid a plumber hundreds of dollars to snake it, and they've been able to snake the drain and remove an unknown blockage (I've heard it's lint probably lint getting caught on old pipes). This year, I decided to rent a snake and I was able to snake the drain successfully. I imagine that I will have to do the same thing about six months to a year from now.
While I was able to do this on my own, It was extremely difficult to get the snake from the drain into the actual pipe. I'd spend 5-10ish minutes trying to get down the drain. Using a combination of random motions, activating the motor, and trying to work with some extra slack I was able to do this successfully twice but the stress it put on the snake broke one tip and may have kinked the cable. In fact, I was only able to get the snake further into the pipes by using the motor which i'm assuming would put stress on the cable.
Question
Is there a trick to navigating a snake down a tight drain into pipes? I would like to keep renting a snake and doing this and don't want to damage equipment (or the stress of not knowing if I can successfully get the snake into the drain).
For context, there is no clean-out between the blockage and the drain, so the 3 different plumbers I've had out have always snaked the drain, and that's also what worked for me.
Here is a really rough image of what I think the drain looks like.


Is this a floor drain? In any case, the long-term solution is to add a cleanout (cutting concrete as needed) though one variant on that is replacing the floor drain with a (modern) floor drain that has a clean-out built-in. There should be a trap on any drain, so there's typically going to be a U-bend (180 degree turn) and an additional 90 degree turn before you get to any pipe beyond that unless you are coming in from a clean-out fitting that avoids snaking through the trap. Much work once, easier ever after.

Yes, it is a floor drain. That makes sense. I'm leery of ripping up so much but at the same time the floor keeps getting flooded and wrecked so it's probably worth it long term.
Is that something that i'd just use a plumber to do? Or wold it involve managing multiple trades?

Plumber should be able to do it, but ask the prospective plumber.

A few things:

I have been there. A LOT. I have done everything from pay a plumber a lot of money to come in the middle of the night - when I was young and didn't know better - which actually many years later resulted in a check from the County because they sued the plumber for overcharging people like me! To pay a handyman more normal rates. To snake it myself with a rental machine (successful but hard work - I now understand why plumbers get the big bucks). To snaking with a small snake (25' powered by a portable drill) which sometimes works depending on how far away the clog is. To using chemicals (sometimes helps). To using carbon-dioxide gadgets (learned that from my handyman - sometimes works).
The most repeatedly successful method I have found is using a decent sized shop-vac (best present I ever got from my father-in-law) in blower mode. But my configuration lends itself to that (and to snaking as well, but that's more work). I have a floor drain near where the kitchen and laundry drains go under the floor. I block the laundry tub drain. I block the kitchen drains by opening up a vertical pipe section and blocking it with plastic bags stretched across the opening. Then I run the shop-vac blower down the floor drain and it works incredibly well. I don't think it will help for roots (I had that a couple of times - plumber or handyman had to pull the basement toilet for a BIG snake job for that) but for most other things it seems to actually work - cheap, easy, effective.
Any drain should have a trap. That is what makes the first few feet of snaking so hard to do. That includes sink, shower, tub, floor drain. Once you get past that, snaking is generally: feed a little, rotate a little, repeat. But getting past the trap can be hard to do - I have twisted snakes really bad trying to get past the trap and nearly given up many times (maybe actually given up sometimes, I can't remember...).
Lint - If your washing machine drains into a laundry tub or if it is a small hose that drains into a large pipe (i.e., the hose can be easily removed from the pipe, then get lint traps. You can get them in small packages at any hardware store, big box store, even grocery stores in my area. Or big packs from Amazon:


Lint traps won't solve 100% of the problem, but they help a lot.

Thank you for this in depth answer! Curious, would a plumber's bladder be in the neighborhood of the shop vac approach?

It appears that idea is similar. The key difference is air (shop vac) vs. water (bladder). If you miss an "exit" point (another drain or a hole in a pipe or whatever) with air then you might get a little sewage or water coming out if the air pressure doesn't unblock the clog. But with water you would end up with possibly a lot of water coming out.
